# How do I write my code to allow a user to change password or change username?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

A part of a website I am making gives the option to the user to change their password. I have configured this code and it works fine.

I now want to add a form to the same page, that gives the user an option to change their USERNAME instead. (Individually, so they change their username but don't change the password).

Do I need to repeat the exact same following code and paste it beneath it, obviously adapting particular words to be for the username not password, or is there a way I can **ADD to the existing code** so that its one single processing code? How do I do this? So for example the first line:

**if ($submit == 'Change Password') {**,

in my head in English language, I'd like the code to say **IF** 'change password' **OR** the 'change username' button is submitted... do the following code etc.

//processing code

```
<?php
require_once('checklog.php');
require_once('functions.php');
// Grab the form data
$submit         = trim($_POST['submit']);
$password       = trim($_POST['password']);
$newpassword    = trim($_POST['newpassword']);
$repeatpassword = trim($_POST['repeatpassword']);
// Create some variables to hold output data
$message        = '';
// Start to use PHP session
session_start();
if ($submit == 'Change Password') {
    include_once('connect.php');
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die("Couldn't find db");
    //clean the input now that we have a db connection                      
    $password       = clean_string($db_server, $password);
    $newpassword    = clean_string($db_server, $newpassword);
    $username       = $_SESSION['username'];
    $repeatpassword = clean_string($db_server, $repeatpassword);
    if ($password && $newpassword) {
        if ($repeatpassword == $newpassword) {
            if (strlen($newpassword) > 25 || strlen($newpassword) < 6) {
                $message = "Password must be 6-25 characters long";
            } else {
                // check whether username exists
                $password = salt($password);
                $query    = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
                $result   = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                //if theres a result change password to new password
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $newpassword    = salt($newpassword);
                    $repeatpassword = salt($repeatpassword);
                    //update password
                    $query          = "UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username'";
                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Update failed. " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                    $message = "<strong>Password change successful!</strong>";
                } else {
                    $message = "User account not found.";
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
        } else {
            $message = "Password must match";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Please enter all fields";
    }
    include_once('db_close.php');
}


include_once('header_logged.php');

?>
```

// the forms to change the password or username

```
!--change password form --> 
To change your Password:

<form method="post" action="changepassword.php">
Current password: <input type='password' name='password'>
<br>
<br>
New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'>
<br>
<br>
Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatpassword'>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change Password'>
<input type='reset' name='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
<p><strong><?php
echo $message;
?></strong></p>


<!--change username form --> 
To change your Username:
<form method="post" action="changepassword.php">
Current Username: <input type='username' name='username'>
<br>
<br>
New Username: <input type='username' name='newusername'>
<br>
<br>
Repeat New Username: <input type='username' name='repeatusername'>

<input type='submit' name='change' value='Change Username'>
<input type='reset' name='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help, very much appreciated.

Comment: I would setup a different page/code entirely, rather than mixing in all that stuff together and it's a lot more manageable.

Comment: Also note that instead of "cleaning" the variables you should bind them to the query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: That's a lot a nested if/elses

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['change'])){
//write your code here
}
```

Comment: Ok cool thank you. Then what do I do for the bits like $password       = clean_string($db_server, $password). Do I just add a new line beneath it and repeat it but put $username instead?